# Why do my selenium tests fail on travis-ci after no code change, while they pass locally?

Tags: javascript, python, django, selenium, travis-ci

I'm having hard times trying to debug a selenium test which passes locally but not on travis.

According to travis build logs, it was passing at build [#311](https://travis-ci.org/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/builds/4743649) but started failing at build [#312](https://travis-ci.org/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/builds/4771234), apparently because of commits [e6ee7de08800...7617088b4ba6](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/compare/e6ee7de08800...7617088b4ba6) - which only includes a new locale (.po) file and version bump.

But the selenium tests pass locally. You can try it:

```
AUTOCOMPLETE_LIGHT_VERSION="master"
CITIES_LIGHT_VERSION="master"

rm -rf autocomplete_light_env/

virtualenv autocomplete_light_env
source autocomplete_light_env/bin/activate
pip install selenium
pip install -e git+git://github.com/yourlabs/django-cities-light.git@$CITIES_LIGHT_VERSION#egg=cities_light
pip install -e git+git://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light.git@$AUTOCOMPLETE_LIGHT_VERSION#egg=autocomplete_light
cd autocomplete_light_env/src/autocomplete-light/test_project
pip install -r requirements.txt
./manage.py test autocomplete_light
```

It will output something like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 49 tests in 22.990s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Maybe there is a problem on travis-ci ? I have no idea. Any help is welcome B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because django selenium tests use multithreading, the webserver and the test running run asynchronously.

Travis-ci is victim of its own success, and it was required to [increase sleep times between requests](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/compare/ad190909ebaa...aa42d50a548b) to fix the build.

-- edit --

I had the same problem with django-session-security 2.0.0, but I found an [interresting pattern that resists to travis](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security/compare/7a76a8149a7f...cf2aa92525c6). Basically, "wait" for stuff to happen instead of "sleep then expect".

Comment: Is this still a problem with travis? I'm having similar issues with my tests

Comment: You can assume travis may be overloaded, spare the resources we share, and thanks travis for making open source software better B)